# Problems finding distance- Haversine

Tags: php

It always gives output as `bool(false)`. I have table column name `LocationLong`and `LocationLat` for database.

```
$ulat = $data['ULat'];
$ulong = $data['ULong'];

$sql = "SELECT PostId, (3959 * acos(cos(radians($ulat)) * cos(radians(LocationLat))
    * cos(radians(LocationLong) - radians($ulong)) + sin(radians($ulat))
    * sin(radians(lLocationLatat)))) AS distance
    FROM VehicleDetails HAVING distance < 250 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0, 20";

$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
var_dump($query);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not considering that your query can fail. Start with:

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die('query fails');

var_dump($query);
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Try this:

```
$ulat = $data['ULat'];
$ulong = $data['ULong'];

$sql = "SELECT PostId, (3959 * acos(cos(radians($ulat)) * cos(radians(LocationLat))
    * cos(radians(LocationLong) - radians($ulong)) + sin(radians($ulat))
    * sin(radians(lLocationLatat)))) AS distance
    FROM VehicleDetails HAVING distance < 250 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0, 20";

if( $query = !mysqli_query($con, $sql ) )
{
    echo "Error occurred! :" . mysqli_error( $con );
}
var_dump($query);
```

#### Don't overlook error check!

You will get description of any error that occurred, so that you can fix it without guessing.

#### HappyCoding

Comment: still the same response bool(false)

Comment: Please check your $con to ensure that you have a connection link to your database. Also please do `var_dump( $sql )` to see things clearly

Comment: Found the mistake and corrected it, Now the query runs but it show distance as 0.

JSON 
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["PostId"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["distance"]=>
  string(1) "0"
}

Comment: I'm glad to be of help.  Please upvote my suggestion to help others. Thanks @uzalshrestha

Comment: still not getting the desired output.
i want my query to show every row that is near to given Lat and Long. how do i do it, above query shows only one row also with distance 0